# How do I see the perspective of other users on my SharePoint site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, modern-experience, administration, sitepages

I am a SharePoint editor at my organization. When I edit pages, and save them as drafts, my view is updated, but not that of every other employee at my organization (as expected). I want a way to be able to go back and forth between the edited version of the site (my view) and the original (others' view).

Right now the only way I know how to do this is to get a coworker of mine and borrow their computer. Obviously, this is not a good workaround.

I need a way to view a SharePoint site from a different user's perspective.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SharePoint online modern experience site pages, you can check the version history of a modern page or news post and compare versions in SharePoint, including comparing changes visually on the page.

You can see when a page was changed and who changed it. You can also see when properties (information about the file) were changed. If you need to, you can restore a previous version or delete a previous version.

1. Go to the page or news post that you want to see a version history for.
2. At the top of the page, select **Page details** and then at the bottom of the Page details panel, select **Version history**.
3. The Version history pane will display, and you'll see a list of published and saved draft versions.

Check this Microsoft official documentation for detailed steps (video included): [Compare page versions in SharePoint](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/compare-page-versions-in-sharepoint-de7ba69d-257d-4201-b787-d5ea89fb2f08)

[image]

Comment: This isn't very convenient. Is there a way to change the default view from the edited version to the actual published version, and have it automatically change to the edited draft upon pressing the "edit" button?

Right now when I visit my SharePoint site, I see the draft that I edited, which is vastly different from the actual published version. I want to see the published version, not the edited version UNLESS I am in the process of editing.

Comment: I don't think this is possible with SharePoint out of the box capabilities. In this case, you will have to create a test/dummy account and use it to see the old version.

Comment: I don't understand why this isn't convenient...you can open the older version in a different tab, then switch back and forth between tabs to see differences.  That seems easy to me I guess.  What you are asking for with the edit button is opposite of how publishing infrastructure was designed to work in SharePoint.  You, the editor and the one with permissions to see draft items, will always see the latest published drafts by intended design.  Besides using another tab, you could view the page in a different browser logged in as a test account that has the same permissions as your other users.